# Console class init function name

Tags: actionscript-3, naming, nomenclature

I developed a static Console class that writes any traces, successes, and errors to a log file. It requires a file path String and a LoaderInfo instance to get started. At the moment, the function is named start(path, loaderInfo). I'm not really feeling the name "start", so I'm wondering if there's something more accurate. To me, start methods always have end/stop methods, but since this one doesn't, "start" doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Don't make it a static class.  Make it an interface/ABC.

Implementations change, and you may want more than one logger some day (including multiple different loggers in the same application).  I have been bitten by other people making this decision on multiple projects already.

...unless your project is tiny and you plan to throw it away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

init (unless thats taken?)

Comment: I typically don't pass arguments through init methods. Is that weird?

Comment: kinda.  I like Damian's 'attach' to a path approach.  or just log(path, info); ?

Answer (score 3):

How about a touch of the Patrick Stewart?

makeItSo();

Comment: Seriously though, I think Justin's suggestion makes sense. I don't feel like a Console should be started either. It might be 'attached' to a stream or set of streams though, I suppose.

Comment: LOL - perhaps Engage is more appropriate?

Like you said, Attach (params, ...) smells right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Console.logTo(path, loaderInfo) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with startLogging(), then to be followed up by stopLogging().